# ASP.NET Identity 2 Simple User Login Example using EF 6 + MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm building a fairly small ASP.NET MVC 5 app using EF 6 and MySQL, and I thought it'd be nice to use Identity instead of rolling-my-own security. I've been at it for days, trying everything I can Google up, but I feel the .NET universe expanding around me. I'm no further ahead.

I simply need login accounts and security for a section of the site I'm building. Some pages are private to subscribers and others are public. I'd like for the Identity tables to be in the same MySQL db that the app utilizes.

The last time I attempted anything like this was the FormsAuth/Membership stuff in ASP.NET 2.0 - and I haven't built anything substantial w/ .NET since then - so very much a beginner w/ Identity.

Here's now this experiment has progressed. I got MySQL working with EF 6 through a series of guides and hacks, and arrived at this for the Code First approach, and worked. Tables were getting generated and data was flowing:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class RwcDataModel : DbContext
{
    public RwcDataModel()
        : base("name=RwcDataModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

[Table("user")]
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("fullname"), StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

    [Column("email"), StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("username"), StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    [Column("password"), StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    [Column("created"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Column("active")]
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}

//...etc - other tables

public class RwcDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<RwcDataModel>
{
    protected override void Seed(RwcDataModel context)
    {
        context.Users.Add(new User { FullName = "Administrator", Email = "me@gmail.com", Username = "Administrator", Password = "password", Created = DateTime.Now });
        context.Users.Add(new User { FullName = "Some Guy", Email = "someguy@gmail.com", Username = "someguy", Password = "password", Created = DateTime.Now });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

...with this in Application_Start() of the Global class:

```
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
        Database.SetInitializer<RwcDataModel>(new RwcDbInitializer());
```

I first tried this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w

...but this just caused my db to be dropped, but not re-created and seeded. Strange, can't explain that.

Thanks to trailmax below, I followed these (similar) instructions:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

...but upon running this iteration of my app, no Identity tables are created. Also, the RwcDataModel above does nothing. The db isn't dropped - it's as if the Initializer is being ignored completely.

Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Asp.net Identity 2.0 is VERY straightforward, and all the features of it are built into the default apps for MVC5 in Visual Studio.

Comment: As it stands now, you haven't actually described a problem or asked a question, except to ask if you should avoid the technology you want to use.  Please see [ask]

Comment: First 2 hits in google give me excellent articles how to implement Identity with MySQL: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider and http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider I think you should start from these

Comment: Pardon the vagueness of the OP. What I had done was create an MVC project with Web API. The built-in stuff wasn't there - no login or register links. My mistake! All I saw was a bunch of generated code with no UI or indication as to how to use it...and tutorials weren't helpful. Will give it another shot now that I can see it working. Thanks.

Comment: Added a bunch of detail to the OP and where I'm stuck at my current point of failure. Would appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: Some (sort of) progress. By doing steps 2 - 5 (adding those items in web.config) in the codeproject article in my post, the identity tables are being generated in the database now. Problem is, they're all named incorrectly, i.e. "my_aspnet_users" instead of "aspnetusers", which throws an exception for a missing table, when attempting to register a new account. Also, none of my code-first entities are generating tables now.

Comment: @TsarBomba don't use that Codeproject sample - it is talking about MembershipProvider, not Asp.Net Identity - these are different libraries/approaches. MembershipProvider is superseeded by Identity. Even if the title says it is about identity, it is simply wrong.

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing that out. I thought the tables looked all wrong, and there were too many of them. Gotcha, @trailmax.

Comment: @TsarBomba when you are replying to somebody in comment, don't forget to mention them, like I've done in the start of the comment. Otherwise people won't see your comments. I'd stay away from CodeProject - a lot of poor quality articles there. Stick with the official sources.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog [ASP.NET Identity 2.1 with ASP.NET Web API 2.2 ASP.NET Identity 2.1 with ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/). Mr. Taiseer Joudeh does a great job of explaining how to use ASP.net Identity 2.1 with the Entity Framework. There is sample code included with the tutorial. While MySQL is not used in the tutorial, the Entity Framework makes it easy to switch to MySQL. Hope this helps. Cheers.